# mother board have usb 3 but it is shown and use as a usb 2 device

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, motherboard, usb-3

I have a motherboard zebh61m2. This one do not have usb3 and only usb2 port is present. But I found a 19pin header with label "f_usb_3.0" on the motherboard, so in hope of it support usb3 I purchased a usb3 connector from amazon. After connecting this usb port i purchased to the 19pin header, system considering it also as usb2.

can anyone help me on why this is not working? I will attach some pictures of my system and things i see.

[motherboard 19pin img](https://postlmg.cc/2LqbNCqb)

[usb device i purchased](https://postimg.cc/VJz1mQz6)

[usb device photo 2](https://postimg.cc/XGLP98qk)

[mother board 2](https://postimg.cc/CzXQCdhX)

[windows device manager](https://postimg.cc/w3BfSD3n)

[speed of transfer](https://postimg.cc/bDrrjm7Z)

Answer (score 2):

> **Intel® 6 series chipset boards**
> Huron River (for Mobile platforms) and Sugar Bay (for Desktop platforms) use third-party USB 3.0 controller and Renesas Electronics USB 3.0 driver.
>
> Source: [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005631/software/chipset-software.html)

Generally, the chipset supports USB 3.0.
But: As being a separate third party chip, you cannot be sure the USB 3.0 chip is present on your board. — They like to save some money and preserve "features" for more expensive boards.

In case of your motherboard supporting USB 3.0 I would expect that your board has at least one USB 3.0 slot (typically marked with a blue inlay).

The 19 pin connector you found is designated for the front panel (Note the last letter `D` vs. `6`):

```
Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family  ...

# Front panel:
... USB Enhanced Host Controller 1C26

# Rear side:
... USB Enhanced Host Controller 1C2D
```

So if you search, you might find a spare square mark for a chip that would have been your USB 3.0 support.

If you want to be sure, you might try a driver update and use
[Intel's support utility (DSA)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/detect.html).

I think you will send back the new USB plate.

Comment: you are right . there is a square mark for a chip that is probably my usb 3 driver. https://postimg.cc/34mk9Yq3

https://postimg.cc/0MjvZsyb

the device read a description : ROOT\USBFUNCTIONCONTROLLER\0000

but since windows cant find anything . i hope this will never work.